How can we connect postgresql from react native directly?
I have an app that has a button, I want to query postgresql database directly when I click on that button.
Is it possible from react native to connect to postgresql database directly?
I do not want to use a server as a middleware and use APIs to to do simple task.
I tried using pg npm package but it did not work as there are many dependencies it has that do not work with react native.

Please read: JDBC vs Web Service for Android
